# javascript: ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, module, ecmascript-6

**es6/Babel:** My folder looks like this:

```
A/
    index.js
    a.js
    ...other
```

I expose contents of `a.js` through the `index.js` file as follows:

```
export { foo, bar } from './a';
```

So that I can import it using:

```
import { foo, bar } from '../A';
```

But now, I want to use `*` in `index.js`, so that in case I export another thing from `a.js`, it automatically gets exposed:

```
export * from './a';
```

But when I do this, I get this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @Andy Can you clarify a bit

Comment: @Andy clearly the environment the OP is using does understand import/export because it's only when using `export * from` that there is an error :p

Comment: you have to use transpiler like babel or traceur to convert it to ES2015

Comment: I *am* using Babel transpiler (sorry didn't mention)

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export):

The following syntax does not export a default export from the imported module:

```
export * from …;
```

If you need to export the default, write the following instead:

```
import mod from './a';
export default mod;
```